# how to add favorite item to favouritefragment on Android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-fragmentactivity

I've an moive application for my campus assignments. I want add to favorite option(in activity) to favoritefragment(new layout) to be implemented. I'm using sqlite. Help me, how  i can add favorite item working. Thank you!

Comment: i think you want to use status. like if user click for like then store 1 and if user is dislike then store 0.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please, provide more info on efforts you made and share some code.

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean @Ali

Comment: Then what's the problem ?? @Riken

Comment: i don't know how i can add favourite working. i have search on youtube but still don't understand :') @Ali

Comment: Please ask your question in details , we did't get it.

What i get that you need something like bookmark / fav so simply add those into sqlite and on another fragment ( Fav fragment ) show these items from sqlite.

Prefer Room for simplicity for DB

Comment: Do you know how to insert data and fetch data from SQLite?? @Riken

Comment: Follow this link and you will get the concept

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/

Comment: yes i know @Ali

Comment: sorry for bad words in my question, i can't stringing words well, lol. but, what you get from my question, that's what i want to ask. @MayankSharma thanks for helping

Comment: If user click on image then insert in database 1. Now fetch this data in any variable. now check the condition if you get 1 from database then you consider user like this post. if user click second time then insert 0. if user get the 0 then use consider this post is dislike. @Riken

Comment: oww, i got it. thanks for helping @Ali

Comment: Yoo welcome @Riken